# Weblogic DEADLOCK weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXATransactionImpl

Tags: weblogic

Weblogic managed serber fails after start with issue:

## DEADLOCK DETECTED:

### [deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':

Thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXATransactionImpl@6d75d9c2' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

### Stack trace:

```
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl.rollback(GXAResourceImpl.java:1506)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.rollback(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1482)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.rollback(XAServerResourceInfo.java:807)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.startRollback(ServerSCInfo.java:880)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.localRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2090)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalRetryRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:3170)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2919)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:442)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.rollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:420)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:570)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke(BaseLocalObject.java:766)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.TimerDrivenLocalObject.postInvoke(TimerDrivenLocalObject.java:79)
    weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl.timerExpired(TimerImpl.java:403)
    weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:284)
    weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

### [deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':

Thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl@7706b14b' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

### Stack trace:

```
    weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl.handleTimeoutFailure(TimerImpl.java:508)
    weblogic.ejb.container.timer.EJBTimerManager$TimerExpirationOperation.onRollback(EJBTimerManager.java:1128)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAOperationWrapperImpl.onRollback(GXAOperationWrapperImpl.java:180)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAAbstractTransaction.loopOperationCallbacks(GXAAbstractTransaction.java:254)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXATransactionImpl.doOperationCallbacks(GXATransactionImpl.java:183)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl.rollback(GXAResourceImpl.java:1555)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl$RollbackRequest.run(GXAResourceImpl.java:1761)
    weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

>
Anybody help

Comment: Better to raise SR with Oracle to get the solution as it's an issue with Product itself.
Which version of Weblogic being used?

Comment: Hi Naveen, Weblogic 10.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange: there is "blocking chains" changed by places - now is weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl  blockcer for weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXATransactionImpl

## DEADLOCK DETECTED:

### [deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '31' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':

Thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '31' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl@1aba871c' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '29' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

### Stack trace:

```
    weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl.handleTimeoutFailure(TimerImpl.java:508)
    weblogic.ejb.container.timer.EJBTimerManager$TimerExpirationOperation.onRollback(EJBTimerManager.java:1128)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAOperationWrapperImpl.onRollback(GXAOperationWrapperImpl.java:180)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAAbstractTransaction.loopOperationCallbacks(GXAAbstractTransaction.java:254)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXATransactionImpl.doOperationCallbacks(GXATransactionImpl.java:183)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl.rollback(GXAResourceImpl.java:1555)
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl$RollbackRequest.run(GXAResourceImpl.java:1761)
    weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

### [deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '29' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':

Thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '29' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXATransactionImpl@5279549f' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '31' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

### Stack trace:

```
    weblogic.store.gxa.internal.GXAResourceImpl.rollback(GXAResourceImpl.java:1506)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.rollback(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1482)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.rollback(XAServerResourceInfo.java:807)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.startRollback(ServerSCInfo.java:880)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.localRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2090)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalRetryRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:3170)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2919)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:442)
    weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.rollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:420)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:570)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke(BaseLocalObject.java:766)
    weblogic.ejb.container.internal.TimerDrivenLocalObject.postInvoke(TimerDrivenLocalObject.java:79)
    weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl.timerExpired(TimerImpl.java:403)
    weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:284)
    weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

SUBSYSTEM = WebLogicServer USERID =  SEVERITY = Critical THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' MSGID = BEA-000394 MACHINE = vs-szp-app-t2 TXID =  CONTEXTID =  TIMESTAMP = 1574697355831
WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset
WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 30000
>

Comment: If you have access to Oracle Support better raise SR with them to get the solution. You may have to provide thread dumps and other data as requested.